# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mockit.Expectations

Tags: java, mockito, jmockit

Why am I getting this error when compiling my application with tests?

I am using jmockit 1.49 with maven but my test code was made for 0.999.15. Now i am migrating the code but i can't execute my tests.

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mockit.Expectations`

```
@Before
@Override
public final void setUp() {
    new Expectations() {
        {
            mockRequestContextHolder.getRequestContext();
            final RequestContext rc = new MockRequestContext();
            result = rc;
        }
    };
}
```

Can anyone help me??